# Cancel button can't shown in GMSAutocompleteViewController

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I added the autocomplete UI control "Add a full-screen control" from

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

and use the below code for presenting the Autocomplete view controller when the button is pressed.

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.delegate = self
present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The below images show what I have got.
Everything is working, But cancel button is only shown when I click there.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using following type code then you are face this problem

```swift
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1)
    ], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

***Solution - Change UIControlState from UIControlState.normal***

```swift
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1)
    ], for: UIControlState.application)
```